# Can't read files from command line. The files are in the same folder. FileNotFountException

Tags: java, file

I am writing this to take in data about books from a txt file. (ISBN, Price, Stock) I keep running into FileNotFoundException problems and cant figure out where the problem is. Sorry if the code is bad or whatever i'm still very now to programming.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;

public class BookInventory {
   static ArrayList ISBN = new ArrayList();
   static ArrayList Price = new ArrayList();
   static ArrayList Stock = new ArrayList();      

   public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{

      if(handleArgs(args)){
         for(int j = 0; j < args.length; j++){
            getInventory(args, j);
         }
      }  
   }

   public static void getInventory(String[]args, int j)throws FileNotFoundException{
      Scanner input = null;
      try {
         File inputFile = new File(args[j]); 
         Scanner booksFile = new Scanner(inputFile);      
         if(booksFile.hasNextDouble()){  

            while (booksFile.hasNext()) { 
               try {
                  ISBN.add(booksFile.next());
                  Price.add(booksFile.next());
                  Stock.add(booksFile.next());
               } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
                  throw ex;
               }
            }
         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         System.out.println("Error: File " + args[j] + " not found. Exiting   program.");
         System.exit(1);
      }
   }
   public static boolean handleArgs(String[]args){
      if(args.length < 2){           
         System.out.println("Incorrect number of command line arguments.");
         System.out.println("Program requires at least 2 files.");
         return false;
      }          
      return true; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: What command line are you using?

Comment: Pass your file names as absolute paths, meaning on Windows they should start with a drive letter and backslash (like `C:\Users\Mowell\books.txt`) and on other systems should start with a slash (`/`).  Any other file name is a relative path, which is interpreted as relative to the current working directory of the Java process.

Comment: You may need to get your current path:

Comment: I am using J-Grasp on windows and the files are in the same folder as the java file so it shouldn't make a difference right?

Comment: The files may be in the same folder, but are they in the *current* folder? Are the names you are passing valid relative to the current working directory? Clearly not.